# How to circumvent VC++2008EE JIT debugging restriction?

Tags: visual-c++

Is there some smart registry hack or so available to get Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition running Just In Time Debugging? Or is there some other (legal) way to circumvent this restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible decent (and still free) alternative would be to install the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/Devtools/Debugging/default.mspx) which will do just in time debugging quite nicely.

WinDbg isn't quite as nice as the VS debugger for a lot of things, but it's pretty close. And it has a lot of functionality that simply isn't in the VS debugger at all (being able to dump important Windows structures for example).